# How can I link these js function and js call to index.js file in cordova(phonegap) project?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

```html
How can I link these js function and js call to cordova(phonegap) project?
***index file***
here is js functions
<html>  
 <head>    
 
    <script>
function SetStart(ss) { 
    Start0 = ss;
    Init(); 
}
    
function Init() {
    //initialization
}
    </script>
 </head>

    ***.and js call in index file.***
 <body>
  <div id ="links">
   <a href="javascript:SetStart(0)"><img src="img/abc.jpg"></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like to help if it would be more clear@SENTIKING

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask